# can't view the transmitted bytes over UART on the received end as expected

Tags: c, embedded, nordic

I wrote a simple function to transmit the data over UART on nRF52 but having trouble seeing data on the receiving end: terminal.
Every time I transmit something, it comes out as **?** in a serial console, whereas if I put breakpoint where I am writing to the `TXD` register, it seems to look fine: I see "hello" on a console.

In addition, I can receive characters from the terminal to my application fine as well (I haven't tried receiving fast enough since I manually type it out).

```c
// main.cpp

Uart uart;  

int main()
{
    char s[] = "hello";

    uart.StartTx((uint8_t *) s, strlen(s));
}

// uart.cpp
bool Uart::getNrfEventStatus(nrf_uart_event_t reg) const
{
    return (bool) *(volatile uint32_t *)((uint8_t *)pUARTx + (uint32_t)reg);    
}

void Uart::TxByte(uint8_t byte)
{
        setNrfEvent(NRF_UART_EVENT_TXDRDY, 0);  
        pUARTx->TXD = byte;
}

void Uart::TxBlocking(uint8_t *buffer, size_t bytesToSend)
{
    for (uint8_t idx = 0; idx < bytesToSend; idx++)
    {   
        TxByte(buffer[idx]);    // NRF_UART_EVENT_TXDRDY is set right after writing to TXD
        
        while (getNrfEventStatus(NRF_UART_EVENT_TXDRDY));     // wait till NRF_UART_EVENT_TXDRDY is reset in IRQ handler
    } 
}

 void Uart::StartTx(uint8_t *buffer, size_t bytesToSend) 
{ 
      setNrfEvent(NRF_UART_EVENT_TXDRDY, 0); 
      setNrfEvent(NRF_UART_TASK_STARTTX, 1);   // trigger NRF_UART_TASK_STARTTX
      TxBlocking(buffer, bytesToSend); 
      setNrfEvent(NRF_UART_TASK_STOPTX, 1); 
}

void Uart::setNrfEvent(T reg, uint32_t value)
{ 
      *((volatile uint32_t *)((uint8_t *)pUARTx + (uint32_t)reg)) = value; 
       #if __CORTEX_M == 0x04 
       volatile uint32_t dummy = *( (volatile uint32_t *) ((uint8_t *)pUARTx + (uint32_t)reg) ); 
       (void)dummy; 
       #endif 
}
```

Another thing I noticed was when I put a breakpoint at `setNrfEvent(NRF_UART_TASK_STOPTX, 1);` , the TXDRDY event remained set despite having a while busy waiting on it clearing out...and I'm not sure why would that be the case despite the register being volatile.

---

I was able to resolve the issue by disabling the interrupt flag for TXDRDY event and by having a busy-wait after writing to TXD to ensure TXDRDY event is set prior to writing back to TXD register again

```c
void Uart::TxBlocking(uint8_t *buffer, size_t bytesToSend)
{
    for (uint8_t idx = 0; idx < bytesToSend; idx++)
    {   
        setNrfEvent(NRF_UART_EVENT_TXDRDY, 0);
        TxByte(buffer[idx]);
        while (getNrfEventStatus(NRF_UART_EVENT_TXDRDY) == 0);
    }
}
```

What I'm still unsure of is how was busy-wait being preempted or affected when TX interrupt flag was initially set as posted in the original post? How does disabling the TX flag make this blocking mechanism work? Was the busy-wait causing the flag to be not set in an interrupt? Because that's what I saw but not sure how it happened. Any inputs?

Comment: You should probably put the `setNrfEvent(NRF_UART_EVENT_TXDRDY, 0); ` inside the for loop in `Uart::TxBlocking` just before `TxByte(buffer[idx]);`. As you have it now, once the interrupt sets that 'ready' flag it stays set for the duration of the transmit and you'll end up overwriting bytes in the TX buffer.

Comment: maybe I'm misunderstanding your point but how does putting `setNrfEvent(NRF_UART_EVENT_TXDRDY, 0);` in `Uart::TxBlocking` before `TxByte(bufer[idx])` make it any different than what it is now? in either cases, TXDRDY flag is reset just before writing to `TXD` register no?

Comment: Are you shure that both the UART and the console use the same number of data bits, same baud rate, same parity and the same stop bits? Tolerance of both baud rates should be less than about 2 %. Did you set the baud rate in code?

Comment: You need to clear that flag every time you transmit a byte, not just once, because it gets set by the interrupt after every byte is transmitted.

Comment: @brhans yes the flag gets set after transmitting each byte but also I am clearing the flag inside the ISR itself...

Comment: @Uwe yes I did set the baud rate to 115200

Comment: @xyf - Hi, Your "answer" was still asking for advice, so it's really an *update* not an *answer*. If you ask for more advice in an "answer" then it becomes a *question* again, and questions are not allowed in the "answer box". Therefore I have moved your update into the question, where it should be. As the OP, you would only write an answer if you solved the problem on your own and the topic can be closed. Please continue to add updates in the question, as you make progress. Thanks.